How to send an email through the aiosmtplib?
I am creating a bot on aiogram. It has to be able to send a message through mail yandex. This is the code for the handler:
@other_router.message(ContactMe.time)
async def cmd_contact_me_4(message: Message, bot: Bot, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(time=message.text)
    await message.answer(ContactMeText.val_success, reply_markup=reply_menu_keyboard)
    data = await state.get_data()
    await state.clear()
    load_dotenv()
    text = await ContactMeText.form_request(*data.values())
    await bot.send_message(os.getenv('ADMIN_ID'), text)
    await send_mail(os.getenv('MAIL'), text)

And the code for the sending utility:
async def send_mail(to: str, text: str):
    load_dotenv()
    login = os.getenv('YAMAIL_LOGIN')
    password = os.getenv('YAMAIL_PASSWORD')

    email = MIMEText(text, 'plain', 'utf-8')
    email['Subject'] = Header('Поступил запрос на обратную связь!', 'utf-8')
    email['From'] = login
    email['To'] = to

    con = aiosmtplib.SMTP(hostname='smtp.yandex.ru', port=465, timeout=10, use_tls=True)
    await con.connect()
    await con.login(login, password)
    await con.sendmail(email['From'], to, email.as_string())
    await con.quit()

However, whenever I run this part of code, I have this error appear:
File "/Users/polina/Desktop/Kineziolog/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiosmtplib/smtp.py", line 425, in connect
response = await self._create_connection(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/polina/Desktop/Kineziolog/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiosmtplib/smtp.py", line 485, in _create_connection
raise SMTPConnectError(
     aiosmtplib.errors.SMTPConnectError: Error connecting to smtp.yandex.ru on port 465: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)


As an aside, it looks like your email code was written for an older Python version. The email module in the standard library was overhauled in Python 3.6 to be more logical, versatile, and succinct; new code should target the (no longer very) new EmailMessage API. Probably throw away this code and start over with modern code from the Python email examples documentation.

Actually, switching to the new library might improve your code already; one of the issues with the older frameworks was that it leaked badly around the use of non-ASCII character sets.

Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47585757/openssl-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate

@tripleee thanks, I'll try. What's the name for the new library?

It's the same library, but you'd use EmailMessage instead of MIMEText and some method names are different (e.g. probably prefer send_message over sendmail)

@tripleee , oh, got you. Thanks

@tripleee and no, that question is not related as it's for Node.js. I guess the solution makes difference

The mechanics of TLS are the same. Your trust chain is broken somewhere, and the question probably isn't answerable until you provide details about that.
